# NLog - Throw exception and log message at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nlog

I have the following method which includes a validation check at the beginning. I'm using `NLog` and I would like to log the exception message and throw the exception 'at the same time', avoiding as much code bloat as possible.

Currently, I do the following, but it seems a bit bulky. Is there a better way?

```
public static void ValidateValue(string value)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && value.Contains(","))
    {
        ArgumentException ex = new ArgumentException(string.Format("value cannot contain ',': {0}", value));
        Logger.Error(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for would be more along the lines of

```
public static void ValidateValue(string value)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && value.Contains(","))
        throw Logger.Error<ArgumentException>("value cannot contain ',': {0}", value);
}
```

where the `Logger.Error<>` method returns the `ArgumentException` after it has logged the message.

This seems like something that would be useful and may well already exist, but maybe I have to roll my own extension method?

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to use reflection to create the exception object if you want to use generics, probably just easier to pass in a new Exception object manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logging and throwing an exception in the same place is not recommend because:

- You could get multiple logs for the same error (on multiple levels)
- You could forget to log an exception

I would recommend the following:

- Catch exceptions on high level and log them there (generic)
- Only log the exceptions where you won't (re)throw them
- Add context info when not-logging them, I use the following helper:

  ```
  public static TException SetContextData<TException>(this TException exception, object key, object value) 
         where TException : Exception
  {
      exception.Data[key] = value;
      return exception;
  }
  ```

  Usage:

  ```
  throw ex.SetContextData("someContext", 123)
          .SetContextData("anotherId", 133);
  ```

  With NLog you could log the exception data as follows:

  ```
  ${exception:format=toString,Data:maxInnerExceptionLevel=10}
  ```

Comment: You are quite right. Logging an exception at the point of it's creation provides no contextual information whatsoever. It's better to log it at the point where the app is going to do something with (or ignore) the error, since additional information about what the error actually represents in the context of the `try {} catch () {}` can be added to the log. Thanks for clearing that up for me :0)